How fast does the Parker solar probe move before/at aphelion?
While the perihelion speed is well recorded, I cannot find anything of the spacecraft's speed before/at aphelion, specifically around intersection with Venus. Does anyone have this info?

In its final orbit, the speed of the Parker Solar Probe is ~11.97 km/s at aphelion. Its orbit is quite eccentric (~0.88) to minimize the time that it gets baked by the Sun. It reaches its final orbit after 7 flybys of Venus. The dates of those flybys (and the perihelia) are listed on its JPL Horizons data page.
Here are some relevant Horizons plots. All times are in TDB (the time scale JPL uses for ephemeris calculations).
Distance from the Sun.

Distance from Venus, showing the last few flybys.

Orbital speed near aphelion.

Orbital speed near perihelion, which is much faster.

If you're curious about its orbital elements, I have a script near the end of this answer; Parker's ID number is -96.

If you know the probe's velocity, $v$, at perihelion, its distance from the sun's center of mass, $r$, at perihelion, and the sun's gravitational parameter ($\mu=GM$), then you can work out the semimajor axis of its orbit, and, with that, its speed at any distance from the sun's center of mass. You will need to use the vis-viva equation for this.
$$v^2=\mu({{2 \over r}-{1 \over a}})$$
To work out the distance from the sun at aphelion, use $$a={r_p+r_a \over 2}$$

Thanks - nice get!
